# C# LINQ to XML: number of elements, that have two same attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have something like this:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Number>
        <Title>
        <Author>
        <NumberOfCopies>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

The `NumberOfCopies` element means how many same copies the library has of the same book. (Same books=same author, same title). The `Number` element is different for each book, it is for storing them in the library.

When I add a new book, I would like to find out how many copies the library has.(int number) How to do this?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("books.xml");
var q = from x in doc.Descendants("Books")
        where x.Element("Author").Value == newBook.Author
              && x.Element("Title").Value == newBook.Title
        select x;

int number = (int)q;
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us the actual XML - we can't tell the structure here. (In particular, you've talked about attributes, but we can't see any...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* you want:

```
var book = doc.Descendants("Book") // Note Book, not Books
              .Where(x => x.Element("Author").Value == newBook.Author &&
                          x.Element("Title").Value == newBook.Title)
              .FirstOrDefault();

if (book != null)
{
    int copies = (int) book.Element("NumberOfCopies");
}
```

This assumes you'll only have one element for a given book, of course.

Comment: Will a simple cast work on `.Element(name)`? Don't you need to actually parse it?

Comment: @J.Steen: Yes, it will work. There are explicit conversions for XElement.

Comment: Sweet. Haven't done a lot with those classes yet. Good to know.